# Bad function call in calling member function pointer from pointer to an object

Tags: c++, oop, lambda, smart-pointers, pointer-to-member

So I am writing a project for an OOP course. I came across this peculiarity.
I have a class with a customizable function, as such:

```
#include<memory>  
#include<functional>
#include<iostream>
class foo 
{
private:
   std::function<void()> action = nullptr;
public:
    foo() = default;
    void add_action(std::function<void()> lambda_expression)
    {
        action = lambda_expression;
    }
    void do_action() 
    {
        action();
    }
};
```

If in main I am to do the following

```
std::shared_ptr<foo> sp;
{
    foo obj= foo();
    sp = std::make_shared<foo>(obj);
    obj.add_action([]() {std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; });
}
sp->do_action();
```

It will invariable will cause the following error:" Unhandled exception at 0x75284192 in lambda expression.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: **std::bad_function_call** at memory location 0x0058F710."

And going into debug autos I can see that it read the action as "empty".

however, switching the order as such

```
obj.add_action([]() {std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; });
sp = std::make_shared<foo>(obj);
```

or using the shared pointer to call add_action():

```
sp = std::make_shared<foo>(obj);
sp->add_action([]() {std::cout << "hello world" << std::endl; });
```

both work fine! (print "hello world")

Note: the normal pointer counterpart to this code does not work in either of these cases.

Does anyone know what could cause this? I am going to look into it but seems to rather subtle!
If I find the reason why I shall post it on this thread. 
Thank you!

Working in Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foo obj= foo();
```

`obj` is constructed by default constructor, so there is no a target in `std::function`.

By

```
sp = std::make_shared<foo>(obj);
```

you create new instance of `Foo` on a heap, whose lifetime is managed by smart pointer `sp`. This newly created `Foo` object has also no a target in `std::function`, because `obj` didn't have target when copying operation was performed. `Foo(const Foo&)` just copied empty function.

After construction of `sp`, these two `Foo` instances are completely unrelated. By accessing `sp` you don't modify `obj`, and vice versa. So `obj.add_action` could not update `std::function` of `Foo` constructed by `shared_ptr`.